# How to get all the parameters that are selected as a rows using row groups in SSRS matrix report?

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, report

I need to get all the values(Suppose Jurisdiction) that are selected in the Parameter(Multi value Parameter). My Stored Procedure is only returning few jurisdictions as the tables are only having that data. But I need to show the other jurisdictions that are selected as input parameters with Null or 0 for the corresponding values.
Like if I selected NJ,VA,IA,NY and my SP for report dataset is getting values for NJ,VA,IA from the table I need to represent these with table values and the NY with Spaces or 0.

Now I am getting

```
                                 Jurisdiction                Value
                                 NJ                           1
                                 VA                           23
                                 IA                           5
```

But I need to get

```
                                Jurisdiction                Value
                                 NJ                           1
                                 VA                           23
                                 IA                           5
                                 NY                           0 or Null
```

Jurisdiction is used as the row group in SSRS matrix report.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your stored procedure. Perhaps the stored procedure is doing an inner join, which eliminates the jurisdictions that do not have related data? Can you change that to a left join so the jurisdiction is always returned whether or not there is data in the related tables?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. I tried using Right join and able to get that. But I wonder if there is any option that i can do at report level than making the changes to procedure. If this is the only option then i will go with that.

Comment: You could modify the SQL query in your datasource, so that you right join to the results of the procedure.   Or maybe you can do a JOIN in your tablix, but that's going to get very complicated and difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches here.

Firstly, if you can alter the stored procedure or write your own SQL for your dataset, then you can do this with a left outer join. For instance, your SQL probably looks something like this:

```
SELECT Jurisdiction, Value
FROM JurisdictionValues
WHERE Jurisdiction IN (@Jurisdictions)
```

This only gives you results that have values. If we left outer join that against the Jurisdictions table then we can return something for all the parameter values selected, even if the value will be null.

```
SELECT J.Jurisdiction, JV.Value
FROM Jurisdictions J
LEFT OUTER JOIN JurisdictionValues JV ON J.Jurisdiction = JV.Jurisdiction 
  AND J.Jurisdiction IN (@Jurisdictions)
```

The other way to do it is to do a lookup in SSRS directly. You will have two datasets, one being Jurisdictions and the other JurisdictionValues. The table for the report is based on Jurisdictions and has the following SQL:

```
SELECT Jurisdiction
FROM Jurisdictions
WHERE Jurisdiction IN (@Jurisdictions)
```

The JurisdictionValues table returns the jurisdictions and values from your stored procedure. In the table cell for the value, put the following formula:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Jurisdiction.Value, Fields!Jurisdiction.Value, Fields!Value.Value, "JurisdictionValues")
```

The Lookup finds the corresponding value for the Jurisdiction and returns the Value field.